# Ansible execute script not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, ansible

I'm tying to run a .sh command in anisble from a task.

So an server backup module installs a .sh file on a designated linux VM and a run module then runs the .sh file.

When I run the job in jenkins, I see the database_backup.sh file has been installed in /temp which is correct.

However when it comes to run the execute module, nothing happens.

**Below is the execute script.**

```
name: Execute Backup Script

command: ./tmp/database_backup.sh 

 become: true

become_user: root
```

Am I missing something from the script?

Comment: Show task output with `-vv` flags. Also I see path missmatch – you talk about `/temp` and try to execute from `./tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with absolute paths: (remove the dot in front of `/tmp`)

```
name: Execute Backup Script
command: /tmp/database_backup.sh
become: true
become_user: root
```